# Handle events from DataTemplate in custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, events, user-controls

I am writing a WPF client and have created a custom Chat control that will be used within the client, the Chat control comprises of a ChatClient that handles joining and leaving the Chat service and displaying a list of connected Users as per the following XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type chat:ChatClient}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type chat:ChatClient}">
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="{StaticResource ChatClientBackgroundBrush}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="135" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="{StaticResource ChatClientBackgroundBrush}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="1,1,1,0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ChatClientAvatarBorderBrush}">
                            <Image Height="80" Width="80" Source="Cleo.Windows.Ui.Chat;component/Resources/noavatar.png" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill">
                                <Image.Clip>
                                    <EllipseGeometry Center="40,40" RadiusX="40" RadiusY="40" />
                                </Image.Clip>
                            </Image>
                        </Border>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Ellipse Height="8" Width="8" Fill="{StaticResource ChatClientPresenceOnlineBrush}" Margin="6,-8,0,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CurrentPerson.Name}" Margin="8,0" Foreground="{StaticResource ChatClientTextBrush}"
                                       FontSize="16" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>

                    <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ChatClientBorderBrush}">
                        <Grid Background="{StaticResource ChatClientBackgroundBrush}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="100" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="srcContacts" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type chat:ChatClient}}}" x:Name="Contacts">
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <ContentControl>
                                                    <Border Style="{StaticResource IsMouseOver}">
                                                        <Grid>
                                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="35" Width="35" Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource ChatClientPresenceOnlineBrush}" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="15">
                                                                <Image Height="30" Width="30" Source="Cleo.Windows.Ui.Chat;component/Resources/noavatar.png" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill">
                                                                    <Image.Clip>
                                                                        <EllipseGeometry Center="15,15" RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15" />
                                                                    </Image.Clip>
                                                                </Image>
                                                            </Border>
                                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="{StaticResource ChatClientTextBrush}" Padding="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"
                                                                   Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </Border>
                                                </ContentControl>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is defined in a ResourceDictionary in the Chat assembly and the ChatClient is added as a control to the main application window.

This is all great and when I run the application it connects to the chat server and I get a nice panel to the right of the main window with a list of connected users.

Ok, so my question is specifically related to the following part from the XAML above:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="srcContacts" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type chat:ChatClient}}}" x:Name="Contacts">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl>
                        <Border Style="{StaticResource IsMouseOver}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="35" Width="35" Margin="5,0,0,0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ChatClientPresenceOnlineBrush}" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="15">
                                    <Image Height="30" Width="30" Source="Cleo.Windows.Ui.Chat;component/Resources/noavatar.png" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill">
                                        <Image.Clip>
                                            <EllipseGeometry Center="15,15" RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15" />
                                        </Image.Clip>
                                    </Image>
                                </Border>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="{StaticResource ChatClientTextBrush}" Padding="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

In the above DataTemplate an item is created for each connected Person, I would like to know how I can handle the MouseDoubleClick event of the `ContentControl` from the ChatClient, so that the ChatClient will be responsible for creating the ChatWindow, examples would be good as still quite new to WPF.

I have been reading up on Attached Behaviors but struggling to understand how these would fit in to what I am looking to achieve which is that my ChatClient class has an event handler that is fired when I double click any item added within the DataTemplate.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this will be greatly received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to fire a `Command` on `MouseDoubleClick` event.

To connect a `MouseDoubleClick` event to a `Command` and pass `ClientId` to it, you can use somethings like this:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="srcContacts" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type chat:ChatClient}}}" x:Name="Contacts">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl>

                         <!-- ــــInputBinding For Mouse LeftDoubleClickــــ -->
                         <ContentControl.InputBindings>
                              <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick"
                                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl},Path=DataContext.ClientDoubleClickCommand}" 
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding ClientId}"/>
                         <ContentControl.InputBindings>
                         <!-- ــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــ -->

                        <Border Style="{StaticResource IsMouseOver}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="35" Width="35" Margin="5,0,0,0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ChatClientPresenceOnlineBrush}" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="15">
                                    <Image Height="30" Width="30" Source="Cleo.Windows.Ui.Chat;component/Resources/noavatar.png" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill">
                                        <Image.Clip>
                                            <EllipseGeometry Center="15,15" RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15" />
                                        </Image.Clip>
                                    </Image>
                                </Border>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="{StaticResource ChatClientTextBrush}" Padding="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Then you can simply define `ClientDoubleClickCommand` `command` in `ClientChat` class (like other members of it such as `People`):

```
public class ChatClient: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //-------- Peopole property --------
    .
    .
    .

    //-------- ClientDoubleClickCommand --------
    ICommand clientDoubleClickCommand;
    public ICommand ClientDoubleClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return clientDoubleClickCommand ??
                (clientDoubleClickCommand = new MyCommand(DoThisOnDoubleClick, true));
        }
    }

    private void DoThisOnDoubleClick(object clientId)
    {
        // Write your target codes (on Mouse Left Double Click) here:
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    //-------- OTHER PROPERTIES AND CODES OF CLASS--------
    .
    .
    .

}

// MyCommand Class: This class is a technique to implement commands easily
public class MyCommand: ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _action;
    private readonly bool _canExecute;
    public MyCommand(Action<object> action, bool canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action(parameter);
    }
}

public class People: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   // ClientId Property:
    .
    .
    .

   // ClientName Property:
    .
    .
    .

   //-------- OTHER PROPERTIES AND CODES OF CLASS--------
    .
    .
    .

}
```

In this example, i assumed you have a `ClientId` property in your `People` class to keep id of each client.

Now you have a `People` property, it is a list of clients and you used it like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People,........
```

On the other hand **if** the `ItemsControl` `DataContext` be »» `ChatClient` class 
**then** we have access to `ClientDoubleClickCommand` in it and access to `ClientId` in `People` class (by `ItemsSource`) in the following line inside `ItemsControl` block:

```
<MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick"
              Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl},Path=DataContext.ClientDoubleClickCommand}" 
              CommandParameter="{Binding ClientId}"/>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer please, how does the ChatClient control bind to the event or command?  I am using a ScrollViewer which does not have an ItemsControl how does your solution fit with this? Could you explain `DataContext.ClientDoubleClickCommand` more clearly please?

Comment: @Neil, i edited the answer and explained more for you in it. I recommend you to use a clear `MVVM` pattern in your project.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you this works a charm, I never cease to be amazed at the power of WPF when i encounter things like this. I did have to make a minor change to the `Command` binding as for my `ItemsControl` was `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People,...' so i had to change the `RelativeSource` in the `MouseBinding` to `Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncesterType={x:Type chat:ChatClient}},...` for the `Path=ClientDoubleClickCommand` to work.

Comment: I'm happy that my answer was useful for you ;)